# how to only see the first row from a column of a data table in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Below I have a code that I have been working on for awhile that is supposed to print the contents of two columns: FILE_DATE_PROCESSED and DATE_ENTERED. I only want the first two rows though. For example, this is the result of my query so far:

```
FILE_DATE_PROCESSED        DATE_ENTERED
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:26:35.180
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:26:34.360
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:26:35.180
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:46:16.350
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 15:00:01.870
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 15:00:03.823
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 15:00:03.403
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 15:59:11.583
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:47:07.900
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:58:19.110
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:20:09.023
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 15:42:25.887
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:26:35.850
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 15:00:02.840
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:58:19.773
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:41:09.040
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:41:09.040
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:58:18.250
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:41:16.877
```

This is the result I want:

```
FILE_DATE_PROCESSED        DATE_ENTERED
2015-12-31 19:32:45.000    2015-06-09 14:26:35.180
```

The syntax is most likely really simple, but since I am fairly new to SQL I am a little unsure on the actual syntax. Below  is the query I am working on:

```
SELECT FILE_DATE_PROCESSED, DATE_ENTERED FROM FILE_DATE_PROCESSED
```

Comment: Which are you using MySQL or MS SQL-Server?  You have both tags and the syntax would be very different depending on the Server type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unclear from your tags, but if this is sql server, use:

```
SELECT top 1 FILE_DATE_PROCESSED, DATE_ENTERED FROM FILE_DATE_PROCESSED
```

Optional: add an `order by` to ensure you get the row you want; e.g.:

```
SELECT top 1 FILE_DATE_PROCESSED, DATE_ENTERED 
FROM FILE_DATE_PROCESSED
order by DATE_ENTERED
```

Edited to add:

If you want the row that was entered last, use:

```
SELECT top 1 FILE_DATE_PROCESSED, DATE_ENTERED 
FROM FILE_DATE_PROCESSED
order by DATE_ENTERED desc
```

Adding `desc` tells SQL to sort the results by the `date_entered` column, latest to earliest, before picking the top one (e.g. the latest row).

Comment: it kind of works. It gives me a date and time, but the date that it is giving me is from tuesday. And I need the most up to date date. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Did you try the first query or the second one @user4970927 ?  I have added a third query that I think is what you are looking for for the additional sorting.

Answer (score 2):

You can change 1 for n number of rows you want to show in mysql.

```
SELECT FILE_DATE_PROCESSED, DATE_ENTERED FROM FILE_DATE_PROCESSED LIMIT 1
```

Use the second for SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 1 FILE_DATE_PROCESSED, DATE_ENTERED FROM FILE_DATE_PROCESSED
```

Comment: 1 doesn't work. I get an error message of Incorrect syntax near 1

Comment: @user4970927 This is correct in MySQL so if you're using Sql Server then remove MySQL in the tags.

Comment: It is removed. It was suggested so I apologize for confusion